# Как в бутстапе сделать колонки не пропорциональные 12?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Возможно глупая у меня проблема но первый раз верстаю на бутстрап:

```css
 .icon {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 .icon-heart {
  background: #19bd9a url(../img/heart.png) center no-repeat;
}
.icon-mouse {
  background: #81868e url(../img/mouse.png) center no-repeat;
}
.icon-bulb {
  background: #81868e url(../img/bulb.png) center no-repeat;
}
.col-md-* {
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2>DetailS ABOUT BOUNCY</h2>
        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-1 ">
        <div class="icon icon-heart"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="icon icon-mouse"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="icon icon-bulb"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Как выровнять по центру 3 круга? md-4 ставлю недастаточно md-5 перелет Как сделать что бы ровно по центру стали?

Comment: если используемый *фреймворк* мешает вам в реализации задумки, то это первый колокольчик что бы написать свою разметку и стили для нее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально в бутстрапе пропорции колонок могут быть кратны 12. У вас 3 элемента которые вы сдвигаете на 4 влево. для того чтобы, выровнять внутри 4 колонок 3 элемента создайте снова ряд, в бутстрапе их можно делать сколько угодно, главное новые `.col` оборачивать в `.row`:

```css
.icon {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon-heart {
  background: #19bd9a url(../img/heart.png) center no-repeat;
}

.icon-mouse {
  background: #81868e url(../img/mouse.png) center no-repeat;
}

.icon-bulb {
  background: #81868e url(../img/bulb.png) center no-repeat;
}

.col-md-* {
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h2>DetailS ABOUT BOUNCY</h2>
      <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon icon-heart"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon icon-mouse"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="icon icon-bulb"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или например в 3 бутстрапе можете воспользоваться [кастомизатором](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) и добавить своё, нужное вам количество колонок в сетку.